# Get titles for links on page and inserting them as title attribute

Tags: javascript, html, dom, hyperlink, href

I am unable to find anything that can let me scan the links on a page and not anchors tn the same page, get their titles without opening the pages, and add the retrieved title as the value of title attribute to that link. Note that title attribute is not there initially. I can use only Java Script. Can anyone help? Is there anyway to do this?

I am most interested in retrieving the titles without opening the links.

-Amit

Comment: You want to find all the links on the page, ajax request to the pages, grab their `<title>`, and then update the links to have those values?

Comment: @Taplar - exactly! Thanks!

Comment: That is a crazy amount of work to make the clients do every time they arrive on your page.  Why are you unable to alter the original markup to include the titles to begin with?

Comment: @Taplar: :-) I thought so. But the markup is already there for all the existing pages (more than 1million) and I cannot and don't want to spend effort for them to add titles. For new markup - this can be done but what about the existing pages? Any way out for them? I just want customers to know where they are heading to before they click a link...